# p12 cert authenticate python

Tags: python-3.x, openssl

Im trying to authenticate with a p12 certicate given by a provider and want to use it to get the html body of the site.

i currently have the following code:

```
import contextlib
import OpenSSL.crypto
import os
import requests
import ssl
import tempfile
import http.client
import shutil
from OpenSSL import crypto

url = "https://website.com/"


p12_cert = "cert.p12"
password = "password"

@contextlib.contextmanager
def pfx_to_pem(pfx_path, pfx_password):
    ''' Decrypts the .pfx file to be used with requests. '''
    with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix='.pem') as t_pem:
      f_pem = open(t_pem.name, 'wb')
      pfx = open(pfx_path, 'rb').read()
      p12 = OpenSSL.crypto.load_pkcs12(pfx, pfx_password)


f_pem.write(OpenSSL.crypto.dump_privatekey(OpenSSL.crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, p12.get_privatekey()))
    f_pem.write(OpenSSL.crypto.dump_certificate(OpenSSL.crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, p12.get_certificate()))
    f_pem.close()
    yield t_pem.name

with pfx_to_pem(p12_cert, password) as cert:
    requests.get(url, verify=cert)
```

ANy guidance is much apprecaited.

Thanks

Comment: `verify=` is for _CA_ certs used to verify the _server_ cert. Use `cert=` for _client_ cert+key. http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#client-side-certificates

Comment: @Pon : I am unable to authenticate using this code as well. Could you please share your part of code ?
While using rest cliend i am able to authenticate and post but with python requests.post my certificate varificantiin fails.

Comment: By the way i too have a p12 certificate with password and i am using above code of yours.

Comment: Also with above code I am getting below error:                                              
 `>>> with pfx_to_pem('C:\\Users\\ukhare\\Desktop\\gos\\trial_tata.p12', 'trialtata') as cert:
...     requests.get('https://IP:8080/siteapi/availabletests', verify=cert)
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "D:\m\Python34\lib\contextlib.py", line 59, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "<stdin>", line 6, in pfx_to_pem
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\ukhare\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmpbx5ru9gv.pem'`

Comment: Hey, can you share a snippet of your code? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can split the p12 file to it's cert/key parts and use them as a tuple with [requests](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#client-side-certificates) as an alternative to a single .pem file path.

Don't forget to delete the key and crt file after you're done in case you do not want to store your unencrypted p12 file permanently and instead want to only decrypt it during runtime.

```
certpw = 'myTopSecretPassword'

# create pem file from p12
p12 = crypto.load_pkcs12(open("/file.p12", 'rb').read(), certpw.encode())

# PEM formatted private key
k = crypto.dump_privatekey(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, p12.get_privatekey())
fkey = open('/myKey.key', 'wb')
fkey.write(k)
fkey.close()

# PEM formatted certificate
c = crypto.dump_certificate(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, p12.get_certificate())
fcert = open('/myCert.crt', 'wb')
fcert.write(c)
fcert.close()

clientcert = ('/myCert.crt', '/myKey.key')

# if you work with a .pem file, you simply use 'cert='/myPEMFile.pem' after dumping the key/cert data in the .pem file
requests.get('https://someurl.org', cert=('/myCert.crt', '/myKey.key'))
```